# Is it always worth to split task between threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I used to think that multithreading is most efficient when we are performing blocking operations and during that time we can proceed with other instructions on another threads.

Recently I have executed simple test. I have created a data vector and splitted equally the rows between threads and compare execution time with one thread worker. The multithreading was the winner.

Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

double g_sum = 0;
std::mutex g_mutex;

void worker(const std::vector<double>& vec)
{
    const auto vectorSum = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.0);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(g_mutex);
    std::cout << "Thread-Worker adding " << vectorSum << " to final sum ("<< g_sum <<")\n";
    g_sum += vectorSum;
}

int main()
{
    const int ROW_SIZE = 10000000;
    const int threadsSize = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << "Task will be seprated on " << threadsSize << " threads\n";

    // data vector with row for every thread
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> dataVector;
    double fillVal = 1.1;
    for (auto i = 0; i < threadsSize; ++i, fillVal += 1.1)
    {
        dataVector.push_back(std::vector<double>(ROW_SIZE, fillVal));
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> threadContainer;
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (const auto& row : dataVector)
    {
        std::thread thread(&worker, std::ref(row));
        threadContainer.push_back(std::move(thread));
    }
    for (auto& thread : threadContainer)
    {
        thread.join();
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::cout << "threads time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

    // main thread only
    g_sum = 0;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (const auto& row : dataVector)
    {
        const auto vectorSum = std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), 0.0);
        std::cout << "Main Thread adding " << vectorSum << " to final sum ("<< g_sum <<")\n";
        g_sum += vectorSum;
    }
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::cout << "one-thread time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```

at wandbox (https://wandbox.org/permlink/qah5auBI3ZoAe7B2) with 3 logical cores, the multithread timing results are twice better than single-thread.

Is my test correct? Can I assume that, skipping additional implementation time,  splitting working task between threads is always better choice?

Comment: No, splitting is not always the right choice. Thread creation is costly. There is no silver bullet - just give your app the option to split between N threads. Some times you could use a threadpool.

Comment: Thread creation has a cost. Synchronization between threads has a cost. The code to create and manage threads has a cost. Threads are not == free performance. They are not always worth it and may sometimes even make things slower. You need a problem where they make sense and where the gains outweigh the costs.

Comment: Try this with a row size of 10.  Including the time to perform output within your timing can skew the results.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis what does Thread-costly mean? Is it only compile-time cost? Please explain further.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Definitely threads are not free perfomance cost, thats why this question exist.... Do you know by any chance how can be cost of thread managment be compared to the profits from its usage?????

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thats why I created solid example. Its obvious threads like every other abstractions have their cost.. When we compute complexity we dont come with arguments for 1-size containers right????

Comment: My question is still actual. When theres a task that can be splitted and be performed concurrently, our machine gives us more than single logical core and the synchronization is minimal - is it better to use threads or no.

Comment: @Piodo you have to profile your specific usage.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis specific usage will have specific solution. Im talking about situation where we got task that can be splitted concurrently with minimal split cost and we own a machine with several logical cores. Will in that case our computer system take an advantage of user-splitted program between cores or single task will be optimized better by the computer.

Comment: @Piodo there is nothing whatsoever compile-time in threading. *All* the issues depend on the OS and your run-time performance of synchronization etc. There is no "minimal split cost", there is "split cost" incurred by the OS, not by the language. There are no optimizations at all. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task based parallelism with a fixed number of threads (no oversubscription) is usually the best performing approach. However, tasks have to have a reasonable size to avoid excessive scheduling overhead. IIRC as a rule of thumb for tbb, the execution of a task should require at least 10k cycles. One important detail you have to be careful about, is synchronization between different tasks. Since you usually don't know on which thread a task is executed, you have to be careful not to introduce deadlocks (e.g., by spawning a task while holding a lock).

However, whether or not a problem can be solved efficiently with multiple tasks highly depends on the specific problem and how it is mapped to tasks. It certainly works well for your example, but this cannot be generalized to be *always the better choice*.

Just a side note: I would recommend to use an existing task scheduling framework (e.g., tbb) instead of rolling your own one.

Comment: This seems to be best answer I wanted to discuss about. Anyway I am going to perform more test under this topic. Thanks

Comment: @Piodo if you are generally interested in the topic of task based parallelism I recommend to check out [Variations on task scheduling for shared memory systems](https://repositum.tuwien.ac.at/obvutwhs/download/pdf/1633888?originalFilename=true).

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple answer. 
The multithread timing results are dependent on realization. It's may be faster or not.
There are many subtle places:

1. Count of hardware threads. If you create 100 threads when hardware threads count is 1, then multithread solution will be slower then single-thread. Because time taken to threads context switching will be too long.
2. Synchronization realization. For example, logging is slow operation. Logging in the context of critical section is bad because it's slow. You can speed up it, if you'll move logging in another thread:
   `std::cout << "Thread-Worker adding " << vectorSum << " to final sum ("<< g_sum <<")\n";`. You can put to another thread values of vectorSum and g_sum and log them. That will be faster then wait for output operation in the locked section.

Comment: I asked about already equally splitted single tasks that can work concurrently. It has been splitted on reasonable amount of threads (std::hardware_concurrency). The synchronization has been minimalized. Question is still not answered.